# Display NULL values in MariaDB (LEFT JOIN gives wrong values)

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

So I am attempting a query selection that SUM's all minutes from an actor's role in 'Sci-Fi' films.
I get the correct values when I do INNER JOIN, but it does not display the NULL values, then when I do LEFT JOIN I get completely different values that are much higher than expected.
Here is the query selection

```
SELECT a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, SUM(allfilms.length)
    AS 'total_combined_film_length'
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN film_actor film_a ON a.actor_id = film_a.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film allfilms ON film_a.film_id = allfilms.film_id
LEFT JOIN film_category film_c ON allfilms.film_id = film_c.film_id
INNER JOIN category c on film_c.category_id = c.category_id && c.name='Sci-Fi'
GROUP BY a.actor_id
ORDER BY (a.actor_id) DESC;
```

The result gives me:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| actor_id | first_name  | last_name    | total_combined_film_length |
+----------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|      200 | THORA       | TEMPLE       |                        287 |
|      198 | MARY        | KEITEL       |                        314 |
|      197 | REESE       | WEST         |                        190 |
|      196 | BELA        | WALKEN       |                         59 |
|      195 | JAYNE       | SILVERSTONE  |                        263 |
|      193 | BURT        | TEMPLE       |                        113 |
```

When in fact I would like the following entries in there as well:

```
|      199 | JOHN        | SMITH       |                           0 |
|      194 | RODGER      | FED         |                           0 |
```

Here is what it looks like when I do LEFT JOIN on the final JOIN, instead of INNER JOIN which is:

```
LEFT JOIN category c on film_c.category_id = c.category_id && c.name='Sci-Fi'
```

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| actor_id | first_name  | last_name    | total_combined_film_length |
+----------+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|      200 | THORA       | TEMPLE       |                       2568 |
|      199 | JULIA       | FAWCETT      |                       1555 |
|      198 | MARY        | KEITEL       |                       4962 |
|      197 | REESE       | WEST         |                       3897 |
|      196 | BELA        | WALKEN       |                       3198 |
|      195 | JAYNE       | SILVERSTONE  |                       3217 |
|      194 | MERYL       | ALLEN        |                       2729 |
```

Thank you, anything helps. Really just curious why the values get all messed up!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, put `c.name='Sci-Fi'` with `where`.

```
SELECT a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, SUM(allfilms.length)
    AS 'total_combined_film_length'
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN film_actor film_a ON a.actor_id = film_a.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film allfilms ON film_a.film_id = allfilms.film_id
LEFT JOIN film_category film_c ON allfilms.film_id = film_c.film_id
LEFT JOIN category c on film_c.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE c.name='Sci-Fi'
GROUP BY a.actor_id
ORDER BY (a.actor_id) DESC;
```

Comment: Still doesn't give the null values

Comment: @MatthewJacobsen just try to debug your query, go one by one with all `JOIN` you have and see which `JOIN` is causing an issue, I am sure you will get the root cause. without looking at test data we may or may not be able to help that much.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to take on problems like yours.  This may be the easiest:

```
SELECT  a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name,
        COALESCE(
          ( SELECT SUM(f.length)
            FROM  film_actor AS fa    ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
            JOIN  film allfilms AS f  ON fa.film_id = f.film_id
            JOIN  film_category AS fc ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
            JOIN  category c          ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
            WHERE  c.name='Sci-Fi'
          )
        ) AS 'total_combined_film_length'
    FROM  actor a
    ORDER BY  a.actor_id DESC;
```

Notes:

- You want *all* `actors`, correct?
- `COALESCE` is one way to turn `NULL` into `0`.
- Tips on efficiency in many-to-many mapping tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- Note that the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary in this formulation.  (And this speeds up the query.)
- If you *also* wanted `COUNT(*) AS number_of_films`, I would recommend a different formulation, probably involving a "derived" table.